# application insights vs elastic (ELK)

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, azure-application-insights

Or I am really bad at searching or there is no detailed comparison between App Insights and ELK stack ?

All monitoring is going to be used for simple Web API, there going to be tons of end points but user traffic should not be too high.

So my question.. Is there any general points/differences when choosing between ELK and App Insights, personally  never had a chance to set up any of those, but before setting up test environment would be nice to know in advance, what to expect/look for.

Comment: It's a bit old, but still... [Choosing centralized logging and monitoring system](https://indexoutofrange.com/Choosing-centralized-logging-and-monitoring-system/#Comparison_table)

Comment: I thought I'm the only one having the same problem. I could not find any other reference apart form the link above. 
@rickvdbosch do you have any other updated reference?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm from App Insights team. I think the link provided by @rickvdbosch in a comment gives quite good perspective. It is 1+ years old at this point, so, some items regarding App Insights evolved since then.

I think App Insights and ELK are quite different offerings. The former is managed offering (you can set it up within couple minutes), focused on very broad range of out-of-the-box experiences (collecting incoming/outgoing requests, exceptions, smart alerts, availability monitoring, analytics, live metrics, application map, end-to-end transactions across apps).

My understanding of ELK is that it has very powerful UI visualization and powerful dashboards (though there are adapters for Kibana to work with Azure Monitor). For scenarios where there is a need to store a lot of data (highly loaded apps with adaptive sampling still store limited amount of data) ELK solution might be cheaper to run.

Answer (score 1):

Final decision was to use ELK as servers already have all the configuration, because other team uses it and mainly because logging will need a lot customization.